# Conditional classnames in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, conditional-rendering

First post in a long time so feeling a little out of the loop. Long story short I'm in a little bit of a pickle. I created a navmenu pop out that toggles classname based on the isActive conditional. works beautifully in React but I can't work out how to implement it in Next.js formatting using the `classname={styles.selector syntax}`. If anyone can advise I'd be grateful.

This is my markup:

```
<div className={isActive ? "drop-menu menu-2" : null}> <a>text</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) library:

Example:

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

// ...

<div className={clsx(isActive ? "drop-menu menu-2" : null)}> <a>text</a></div>

// or

<div className={clsx(isActive && "drop-menu menu-2")}> <a>text</a></div>
```